# React ant design date time picker time not update on the top

Tags: css, reactjs, antd

I'm using my react project for **[ant design 3 date-time picker](https://3x.ant.design/components/date-picker/)**, i want to know how to show when select the currant date with time

**here the  conflict**

> 1st select future date and select time 8 am or 7 am, , then again
> click select date and pick today date , when i click the 1st time
> future date and 7 or 8am . that time display with today date, because
> i m disabled past time with today date , that is a issue , you can
> check

anyone know the solution?

**[stack blitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-jddtiq?file=index.tsx)**

[image: image description here]

**code part here**

```
   class App extends Component<AppProps, AppState> {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: 'React',
      date: new Date()
    };
  }
//date disable
    disabledDate(current: any) {
        // Can not select days before today and today
        //return current && current < moment().endOf('day');
        return current && current < moment().startOf("day")
    }

    //time disable
    getDisabledHours() {
        var hours = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < moment().hour(); i++) {
            hours.push(i);
        }
        return hours;
    }

    //time disable
    getDisabledMinutes = (selectedHour: any) => {
        var minutes = [];
        if (selectedHour === moment().hour()) {
            for (var i = 0; i < moment().minute(); i++) {
                minutes.push(i);
            }
        }
        return minutes;
    }



    //set date
    setDate(d:any){
        console.log("date object is: ", d);
        console.log("date  is: ", d.date());
        console.log("month is: ", d.month()+1);
        console.log("year is: ", d.year());
        console.log("Time :",moment(this.state.date).format("h:mm:ss A"))
        this.setState({date: d})


         const now = moment();  //get current date time
  const isFuture = d.isAfter(now); //check selected date is a future date compared to current date and time
  this.setState({date: isFuture ? d: now.toDate()}); //if it's a future date then assign the slected date else select the current date and time

    }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <DatePicker
   name="Date" disabledDate={this.disabledDate}
   onChange={d => this.setState({date: d})}
   style={{width: "100%"}}
   showTime={{ disabledMinutes: moment().date() < moment(this.state.date).date() ? undefined : this.getDisabledMinutes, 
   disabledHours: moment().date() < moment(this.state.date).date() ? undefined : this.getDisabledHours}}
 placeholder="Select Date & Time"
   
  />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: How will you switch from time picker to date picker then ?

Comment: @aquinq hello,  I don't want to switch from time picker to date picker, first time already opening date picker, do you know the solution?

Comment: I can't find any prop for it, it's probably a default behavior you cannot customize. Maybe you can try to target it using css and hide it this way.

Comment: @aquinq , yes i tried to using `ant-calendar-time-picker-btn {display:none}` its hiding both of button, time and date, i cant understand that  how to coming  that prop

Comment: You are right, I don't think you can change it.

Comment: Thanks for your time buddy, i will try some solution

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216295/discussion-between-core114-and-aquinq).

Comment: what do you mean by " i want to know how to show when select the currant date with time"?

Comment: @AliKleit Hello there, please see my live code https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-jddtiq?file=index.tsx , and  `1st select future date and select time 8 am or 7 am`, , then again click `select date and pick today date` , when i click the `1st time future date and 7 or 8am` . that time display with `today date`, because i m `disabled past time with today date` , time not update with today date and currant time,  that is a issue , you can check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, you can do something like this

1. Set the `value`
2. `onChange` check if the date is future or less than the current time, based on that you can set the date

```
// this will display the selected date
value={moment(this.state.date)}

onChange={d => {
    // checking if selected date is greater than current time
    // if then pass as it is, else pass the current time
    const date = moment() < moment(d) ? d : moment();

    // based on that we'll set the date
    this.setState({date})
}}
```

**[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-datepicker-min-issue?embed=1&file=index.tsx)**

Comment: Hello there i have some small conflict , can you please got to future date and select future time, then again select date and choose currant date , when that moment time is not update,  please look at this https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-datepicker-min-issue?embed=1&file=index.tsx

Comment: @core114, will you please provide the exact steps, I've selected 25 July 2020 8:00 AM and then I selected the current date and it's showing me current date with current time as 8:00AM is disabled, so it will pick current available time.

Comment: Hello, Yes, select 25 and choose future time like 8.pm , then select date and choose currant date time not updating with like a previous  solution

Comment: @core114, if you select 25 8PM, and if you select current date it will be 23 8PM, because 8PM is still available, then you can select the time to current one. this is how it works, what is your expected behavior, how it should work?

Comment: Thanks for the advice, i got the point , but any solution for the change it with currant time ?

Answer (score 0):

You can target the element by css and adding display: none; property to it.

```
.ant-calendar-time .ant-calendar-footer .ant-calendar-time-picker-btn {
    display: none
}
```

Comment: hello there, Its not solution, i already do that, its hiding select and time both of buttons, i update my question

Answer (score 0):

The following css seems to work for me

```
.ant-calendar-time .ant-calendar-footer .ant-calendar-time-picker-btn { display: none; }
```

**EDIT**: the following script block in the index.html can get this done for you...

- When you toggle between the 'select date' and 'select time' buttons, one additional div is added to the DOM; so we seek this additional div on each click (you can add an eventlistener for keypress also if you'd like) and if we find it, we know that the button needs to be displayed - else if we get null, we hide the button;
- I don't know how you will toggle if the button dissappears, so you can change the color of the borders (in my stackblitz) to see the concept working

relevant code for `<script>`:

```
<script>
    window.addEventListener("click", checkClass);

function checkClass(){
    var allBtns = document.querySelector('.ant-calendar-time .ant-calendar-time-picker');
    var relevantObj = document.querySelector('.ant-calendar-time .ant-calendar-footer .ant-calendar-time-picker-btn');
  if (allBtns === null) {
    relevantObj.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    relevantObj.style.display = "block";
  }
}

</script>
```

updated [stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-k6u3dq)

Comment: hello there, Its not solution, i already do that, its hiding select and time both of buttons, i update my question